# "uniquely written" definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

I'm having troubles with this definition:

[image]
[image]

My problem is with the *uniquely part*, for example the zero element:

$0=0+0$,

but $0=0+0+0$

or $0=0+0+0+0+0+0$.

Another example, if $m \in \sum_{i=1}^{10} G_i$ and $m=g_1+g_2$, with $g_1\in G_1$ and $g_2\in G_2$,

we have: $m=g_1+g_2$ or $m=g_1+g_2+0+0$.

It seems they can't be unique!

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The sum must be over the whole set $\Lambda$.

Comment: Equivalently, you should regard two expressions as the same if they're the same except for the insertion or deletion of $0$s.

Comment: @roger yes, of course, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well notice what the definition says. It says that for each $m \in M$, you need to be able to write $m= \sum\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} g_{\lambda}$ where this sum is over all $\lambda$. So for $0$, the only possibility is a sum of $0$ $\lambda$-many times.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of **nonzero** elements is unique. In the case of the element $0$ the set of nonzero elements summing to zero is the empty set.

Comment: I can't make sense of your second sentence.

Comment: @Qiaochu hopefully the second sentence now makes sense.

Comment: The author didn't say anything about **nonzero** elements. according to his definition, the expression I wrote of $0$ is allowed.

Comment: The examples in your question show that if $0$'s are allowed in the sets there is no uniqueness. Sometimes authors forget about stuff like this.

Comment: @Jay: no, there is still uniqueness if you require all sums to involve all summands as in roger's comment.